# Как правильно реализовать указатель на указатель?

Tags: c++

Давно не писал уже на плюсах, совсем забыл про указатели.
Поэтому я опишу задачу немного абстрактно.
Представим, что у нас есть лоточек с фруктами. Нам нужно знать, какой фрукт стоит первым и каждый фрукт "должен знать", за кем он стоит и если что, меняться местами.

```
// опишем наш класс фруктов в Fruit.h
class Fruit {
  Fruit *previousFruit = nullptr; // у каждого есть указатель на предыдущий или пустой указатель, если он первый в списке
  Fruit *nextFruit = nullptr;
}

// в main.cpp теперь мы создадим несколько фруктов
Fruit apple;
Fruit peach;
Fruit orange;

// здесь у нас имеется указатель на первый фрукт
Fruit *firstFruit;

// мы можем его проинициализовать адресом
firstFruit = &apple;

// и проинициализируем указатели между каждым фруктом
apple.nextFruit = &peach;

peach.nextFruit = &orange;
peach.previousFruit = &apple;

orange.previousFruit = &peach;
```

А теперь я хочу реализовать метод eat() внутри класса Fruit, вроде как "съели наш фрукт". 
Он должен переприсваивать указатели.
Но возникла заморочка с указателем на первый фрукт.

Надо как-то передать "указатель на указатель" и переприсваивать его. Только я не соображу как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Зачем чего-то куда-то передавать? У объекта класса уже и так есть этот указатель. Зачем его "передавать" ?

Comment: Очень похоже на реализацию двусвязного списка. Если бы не нужна была смена элементов, то можно было бы обойтись и односвязным. Изучите, возможно поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить данную проблему мне пришлось использовать указатель на указатель.

```
class Fruit {
public:
  Fruit *previousFruit = nullptr;
  Fruit *nextFruit = nullptr;
  Fruit** firstFruit; // объявляем указатель на указатель

  void eat() {
   // например мы съели первый фрукт
   // для этого мы получаем адрес в памяти указателя на первый фрукт
   // и в этот адрес записываем адрес указателя на следующий фрукт относительно съеденного 
   *this->firstFruit = this->nextFruit;
  }
}
```

Немного сложновато, но при таком подходе наш лоточек может быть пустым. Для этого случая мы можем поместить в `firstFruit` значение `nullptr`.

Довольно забавно, но данный подход может вызывать методы первого фрукта из любого другого.

```
(*(*this->firstFruit)).peel(); // двойное разыменование требует скобок
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Зачем? Зачем здесь "указатель на указатель"? Куда он указывает? Какое это все имеет отношение к исходной задаче? (И нет, "двойное разыменование" НЕ требует скобок.)

Comment: Внутри класса фрукта мы держим частный указатель на глобальный указатель, который должен указывать на первый фрукт. Это дает возможность менять глобальный указатель изнутри объекта.

Comment: Какой в этом смыл? Почему бы напрямую не работать с глобальным указателем (на то он и глобальный)? И почему здесь вообще используется *глобальный* указатель? Глобальные переменные - зло.

Comment: Я тут расписываю про фрукты, но могу дать вполне конкретный пример, как это используется. У меня есть проект на ардуинке, там отображается меню на экране. Меню имеет древовидную структуру, по которой можно перемещаться вверх-вниз. Можете сами посмотреть https://github.com/zoonman/nanodds/blob/master/src/main.cpp Обратите внимаение, что некоторые методы работают с currentMenu, которое меняется из-за перемещения по дереву.

Comment: Я не претендую на знатока C++, просто так у меня все заработало, как ожидалось. В сях я полный нуб. Просто мне нужно вызывать действия в контексте конкретного меню.